# How to make iptables ALLOW rule for multicast?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, failover, ucarp

I have two servers that uses ucarp as failover. On each server `eth1:1` is reserved for ucarp's keepalive connection.

ucarp uses the destination IP as multicast address `224.0.0.18`.

On ucarp master server is `eth1:1`'s IP `192.168.245.2` and on the secondary serve is `eth1:1`'s IP `192.168.245.3`.

**Question**

I would like to make an iptables rule on each server, so these NIC's are not used by anyone by mistake. I.e. drop everything expect for ucarp.

How would such a rule look like for the master server?

I assume something like this?

```
iptables -P INPUT -i eth1:1 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1:1  ? something with multicast ?  -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1:1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

Make sure that the `xt_pkttype` module is loaded into the running kernel:

```
--- Networking support        
      Networking options  --->
          [*] Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter)  --->
              Core Netfilter Configuration  --->
                  <*>   "pkttype" packet type match support
```