# Keepalived sync daemon

Tags: keepalived, lvs, ipvs

I've enabled `lvs_sync_daemon_interface` option however it looks like sync daemon is not working

Active node:

```
[MASTER:~]# ipvsadm -Lnc
IPVS connection entries
pro expire state       source             virtual            destination
TCP 00:37  SYN_RECV    192.168.1.20:55746 192.168.1.10:80    192.168.1.15:80
```

Passive node:

```
[BACKUP:~]# ipvsadm -Lnc
IPVS connection entries
pro expire state       source             virtual            destination
```

Config:

```
! Configuration File for keepalived

global_defs {
    lvs_id lb1 #lb2 on backup server
}

vrrp_sync_group VG1 {
        group {
            LB1
        }
}

vrrp_instance LB1 {
    state BACKUP #BACKUP on backup server
    interface eth0
    lvs_sync_daemon_interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 50
    priority 2 #1 on backup server
    nopreempt
    advert_int 1
    smtp_alert
        authentication {
            auth_type PASS
            auth_pass $PASSWORD
    }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            192.168.1.10
        }
}

virtual_server 192.168.1.10 80
    delay_loop 5
    lb_algo wlc
    lb_kind DR
    protocol TCP
    ha_suspend
    sorry_server 127.0.0.1

        real_server 192.168.1.15 80 {
            weight 1
            inhibit_on_failure
                HTTP_GET {
                    url {
                 path /
                 status_code 200
                    }
                    connect_timeout 5
                    nb_get_retry 3
                    delay_before_retry 1
                    connect_port 80
                fwmark 80
                }
        }

        real_server 192.168.1.16 80 {
            weight 1
            inhibit_on_failure
                HTTP_GET {
                    url {
                         path /
                         status_code 200
                        }
                    connect_timeout 5
                    nb_get_retry 3
                    delay_before_retry 1
                    connect_port 80
                fwmark 80
                }
        }
}
```

System: CentOS 6.5, Keepalived v1.2.7 (02/21,2013)

**Update: Sat Jul  5 08:44:36 BST 2014:**

```
[MASTER]# ps -elf | grep [i]pvs
1 S root     11207     2  0  80   0 -     0 sync_t 08:41 ?        00:00:00 [ipvs_syncmaster]

[BACKUP]# ps -elf | grep [i]pvs
1 S root      6231     2  0  80   0 -     0 sync_t 08:41 ?        00:00:00 [ipvs_syncbackup]
```

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I've played with lvs and sync but I'd start troubleshooting without using keepalived for starters and just work with ipvs itself.

From the [lvs documentation](http://www.ntua.gr/lvsp/Joseph.Mack/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.server_state_sync_demon.html#LVS-HOWTO.server_state_sync_demon):

On the primary load balancer, run

```
primary_director:# ipvsadm --start-daemon=master --mcast-interface=eth0
```

On the backup load balancers, run

```
backup_director:# ipvsadm --start-daemon=backup --mcast-interface=eth0
```

To stop the daemon, run

```
director:# ipvsadm --stop-daemon
```

Note that the primary talks to the backup over multicast. You'll need to ensure this traffic can flow from primary to backup. Try allowing [multicast](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml) via [iptables filtering](https://serverfault.com/questions/325652/how-to-make-iptables-allow-rule-for-multicast) on the backup to test for starters.

Set that up and see if you get any output from your `ipvsadm -Lnc` command on the backup.

Also, note that there isn't any ipvs process per se. Think of ipvs as a kernel interface managed by the userspace program `ipvsadm`.

You should also check that both master and backup are configured with the same syncid. This is specified with the `--syncid` option to the ipvsadm commands above. If these are set differently then the backup will ignore anything it receives from the master.